# Why gem devise redirect to sign up path after user signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an `after_sign_in_path_for` method in my application_controller.rb The method is successfully called after a user signs in (I checked with a raise). Unfortunately, after a successful sign in the user is always redirected to `new_user_session` (/users/new) instead of my `dashboard_path` (/dashboard). I want the user to redirect to dashboard path after he signs in. Do you have any clue what can override my redirection to dashboard_path?

Here is my code

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    dashboard_path
  end
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  end
end
```

**Logs**

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-17 14:48:22 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1vtsPGq6tRhJAjUn+hwoMIwfeDjOEMzpEejQVQfT9r/4B1aMv7B727E71F3qLoobyUN5mQkWLzbo/RNxHWZQJQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"tdesfrancs@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "tdesfrancs@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 303ms (Views: 120.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Comment: Do you have any other `before_action` that preventing this? Update the question with the related server log.

Comment: Can you update the question with `sessions_controller` ? Do you have any `before_action` in sessions_controller ?

Comment: Ok, You have a `ROLLBACK`. Check whether the login credentials are correct or not. Or check whether any **validations** are failing

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I check the login credentials? It's strange because the connection is still accepted

Comment: In the code   before_action :authenticate_user!
executed first thats why its redirecting to login page put it some where else

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies If thats the case, there should be something like **filter chain halted** in the log.

Comment: You can put it on specific controller or you can write it like that
before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:after_sign_in_path_for]

Answer (score 0):

You can go even farther by setting `stored_locations_for(resource)` to nil, and then have different redirects for each action, ie: `after_sign_up_path(resource)`, `after_sign_in_path(resource)` and so on.

# routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

## registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    dashboard_path
  end
end
```